# Output values from nested Api/Laravel Collection response in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to output values from an `axios` promise to my `vue` component. So far I'm still getting an error `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'surname' of null"`. Below is what my code looks like

```
<template> 
  <div> 
     {{user.surname}}
  </div>
</template>
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

<script>
   export default {
   name: 'EmployeeCard',

   data(){
     return{
       user: null
     }
   },

   methods:{
     getUser(){
       axios.get('/api/users/'+ this.$route.params.id)
            .then ( response => {
                    this.user = response.data.data; 
             })
     }
  },

  mounted(){
     this.getUser();
  }

  }
</script>
```

This is the actual data returned from the `api`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "data": {
                "id": 11,
                "surname": "Hand",
                "first_name": "Westley",
                "other_name": "Collier",
                "email": "ole48@example.com",
                "phone_number": "306-755-6192 x493",
                "birthday": "06/21/1991",
                "company_id": 3,
                "department_id": 6,
                "job_id": 1,
                "state_id": 11,
                "marital_status": "married",
                "gender_id": 2,
                "photo": null,
                "is_admin": 0,
                "date_of_employment": null,
                "job": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "HR Manager",
                    "comment": null,
                    "created_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42",
                    "updated_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42"
                },
                "department": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Technical",
                    "created_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:43",
                    "updated_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:43"
                },
                "gender": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Female",
                    "created_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42",
                    "updated_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42"
                },
                "company": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Cometshipping",
                    "created_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42",
                    "updated_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42"
                },
                "employmentstatus": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Full Time Permanent",
                    "comment": null,
                    "created_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42",
                    "updated_at": "2019-10-30 17:38:42"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting? You should add a catch to your promise to see any errors

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'surname' of null"

Comment: you need to initialise your user object in data, with said properties you are using, as its already null, you need to make user an object and then initialise rest of the values: `user: { surname: '' }`

before mounted hook it created the component and uses the data, which is still `null` and mounted calls after render the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user variable will initially be null, and you can't get properties from a null value. Therefore, you should replace `{{ user.surname }}` With `{{ user ? user.surname : '' }}`.

Another issue is that the `data` property from your response is an array, not an object, so in your mounted hook you can't do `this.user = response.data.data`. Instead, you should do `this.user = response.data[0].data`.

That way, while your user isn't fetched you'll display an empty text instead of getting an error.

Also, I suggest you add a `catch` hook to your promise to tend to any possible errors.

Comment: it's just blank @Ayrton, not sure if there is an error on my `catch` hook

Comment: @codervine try what I added on the edit, second paragraph

Comment: I have done this `response.data.data[0]` then on my `template`, `{ {user.data.surname }}` displays but I still have this error `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null"`

Comment: @codervine no, just go to your mounted hook and replace `this.user = response.data.data` with `this.user = response.data[0].data`.

Comment: `this.user = response.data.data[0].data;` is what is working very perfectly Thanks... you can update your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<template> 
  <div> 
     {{surname}}
  </div>
</template>
<!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

<script>
   export default {
   name: 'EmployeeCard',

   data(){
     return{
       user: null
     }
   },

   computed: {
    surname () {
     if (this.user) {
      return this.user.surname
     }
    }

   }

   methods:{
     getUser(){
       axios.get('/api/users/'+ this.$route.params.id)
            .then ( response => {
                    this.user = response.data[0].data; 
             })
     }
  },

  mounted(){
     this.getUser();
  }

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template> 
  <div> 
      {{ user.surname }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: 'EmployeeCard',

    data(){
        return{
            user: {}
        }
    },

    methods:{
        getUser(){
            axios.get('/api/users/'+ this.$route.params.id)
        .then ( {data} => {
                this.user = data[0].data; 
         })
        }
    },

    mounted(){
        this.getUser();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit this answer to include a bit of explanation of why whis solves the problem in question